# How Create Guid-string for id column in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

When I was looking at the asp.net Identity 2 sample, I found an interesting point.

The point here is that using the **Guid** in the **id column**.when i  to table definition (example: AspNetRoles table) I saw the command below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles] (
[Id]   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

in show table data i saw value of id:

```
5de2f031-e329-42b8-868e-c402acc18969
```

Really like to **Guid**

also i went to models folder and saw **RoleViewModel** model

```
  public class RoleViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "RoleName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I decided to change the column in my project like the above code (string Guid)

I change my model from **long id** to **Guid Id**

```
 [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
```

But in my table definition is:

```
[Id]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) NOT NULL,
```

I know i must change **Guid** to **string** ,But how does the database automatically convert **Guid** to **string** ? (I mean the auto increment sql server section or Attribute Function [DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)])

In addition, the following code, written for Guid, is also exceptionally encountered:

```
public bool RegisterUser(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        var currentUser = (from u in _allUsers.AsParallel().AsUnordered() where u.EnDecryptedMobileNumber == registerViewModel.MobilePhone select u).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] salt = _hashingClass.GenerateSalt();
        byte[] key = _aesCryptography.GenerateRandomNumber(32);
        byte[] iv = _aesCryptography.GenerateRandomNumber(16);
        User user = new User()
        {
            Key = key,
            Iv = iv,
            Salt = salt,
            EnDecryptedMobileNumber = registerViewModel.MobilePhone,
            EnDecryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(_hashingClass.HashPassword(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registerViewModel.Password), salt, 100000)),
            RoleId = Guid.Parse("04B9CE68-61AE-4EC9-A38B-71823DC91026"),
            Status = StatusType.Accepted,
            RegisterDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastEntryDate = DateTime.Now,
            Sex = registerViewModel.Sex
        };
        base.Add(user);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And Exeption:

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Roles_RoleId\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"GbDb\", table \"dbo.Roles\", column 'Id'.The statement has been
>   terminated."}

**---Update---**

I used entityframwork code first ,I initialized the role in **Configuration.cs** file:

```
    context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Id,
        new Role() { Id = Guid.ParseExact("04B9CE68-61AE-4EC9-A38B-71823DC91026", "D"), RoleInSystem = "User", RoleName = "user" },
        new Role() { Id = Guid.ParseExact("A79383E3-E22D-46AE-8EE6-E61873315BED", "D"), RoleInSystem = "Coach", RoleName = "coach" },
        new Role() { Id = Guid.ParseExact("16BE238F-94B3-4B23-B3A9-10B697707138", "D"), RoleInSystem = "Admin", RoleName = "admin" }
        );
```

(Create manually Guid via visual studio)

But when execute **update-database** and runnig seed method , ids  changed to a new value and stored in the database ! (i don't know why)

My Question is how can create **string-Guid** type like identity 2 id column type with create automatic for each records ?

And for second question why change ids to new guid when running seed method ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to create a link to the role that does not exist (`04B9CE68-61AE-4EC9-A38B-71823DC91026`) - the problem is precisely this.
If you want to create the roles yourself, then you can create the guid for role using `Guid.NewGuid()` method, and change `DatabaseGeneratedOptionAttribute` value to `None`
If you want to create a user with a link to an existing role, you must first select it by some parameter (for example, name), and then substitute the value. (e.g. `5de2f031-e329-42b8-868e-c402acc18969`)

Comment: You are right,my problem solved with Guid, but I'm still waiting for the answer to my questions

Comment: @arman, You wrote "ids changed to a new value and stored in the database": 2. May you select all roles from database. Are there still three? May you set `DatabaseGeneratedOption` to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`. How does the initialization lead after that?

Comment: I realized,Whenever seed method runs, seed method values are executed with a new id.but why identity id type is`NVARCHAR (128)` and my id is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newsequentialid())` ? how can create `NVARCHAR (128)` with **Guid**

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this can work: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT 
 (convert(nvarchar(128), newsequentialid()))`